# How do I hook into WooCommerce product category updates?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When a WooCommerce product category is updated via either of the following two methods, I have not figured out how to hook into the update with `add_action`:

- Reorder subcategories in a category (in the WordPress dashboard, under Products: Categories, drag and drop to reorder subcategories under a parent category)
- Add an existing product to a product category

For the latter, I can hook into the product update -- `add_action('publish_product', ...)` -- but not the category update, which is now updated by the addition of one product.

Here are the hooks that I've tried:

```
add_action('create_product_cat', 'my_update', 10, 1);
add_action('edit_product_cat', 'my_update', 10, 1);
add_action('created_product_cat', 'my_update', 10, 1);
add_action('edited_product_cat', 'my_update', 10, 1);
add_action('product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'my_update', 10, 1);
```

Could someone help me understand how to trigger `my_update()` when a category is updated as described above? Ideally, the product category ID could be passed as an argument to `my_update()`.

I'm using WooCommerce 3.2.5 on WordPress 4.9.6.

Comment: There is an action called "woocommerce_after_set_term_order" that is fired after a product category is re-ordered. Unfortunately it seems to fire for every single product category at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could try these:

```
woocommerce_api_create_product_category
woocommerce_api_delete_product_category
woocommerce_api_edit_product_category
```

http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.6/actions/#index=a

Comment: That says api in the name.